# lirc setup setting protocol

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, lirc

Have question about completing lirc setup. I have almost all working out except ... ;)
So my sensor is working I see events on test with mode2

`sudo mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`

But next steps are working only temporarily when I run `sudo ir-keytable -p all`
How I can enable protocol that is not enabled by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to enable my Sony protocol permanently but not sure it is the right way.

I created new keymap file in `/etc/rc_keymaps` called `scepre.toml` with just basic keymaps.

```
[[protocols]]
name = "sony_RM-ADP090_3"
protocol = "sony"
variant = "sony12"
[protocols.scancodes]
0x10015 = "KEY_POWER2"  # TV power button
0x10012 = "KEY_TV_VOL_UP"
0x10013 = "KEY_TV_VOL_DOWN"
0x10025 = "KEY_TV_SOURCE"
```

And added it to autoloaded keymaps in `/etc/rc_maps.cfg`
by adding this line

```
*   *   scepre.toml
```

Now after reboot I see my remote events in irw even from keys that are not in `scepre.toml` but in `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`